# Extract municipalities on position of point layer (geom within)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am looking for an expression to extract/import the municipality of the position from different points. I have about 400 points and I would like to add a row with the municipalities to these points.
I know that there is an expression like "geom_within" but I can't remember how it exactly was.

Comment: Are you asking how to run the `join attributes by location` tool?

Comment: No, i am looking for that "geom_within" expression that I have used two years ago but it seems to be not available anymore.

Comment: Use [overlay_within](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-within)